# ODBC on Mac Lion with Ruby Sequel

Tags: ruby, macos, odbc

I'm having issues getting Sequel to connect to a MS SQL Database.
I have installed the following:

- UnixODBC
- FreeTDS

I have configured both software packages, and the following commands allow me to connect to my database without a problem:

- isql
- tsql
- osql

However, when I try it from Ruby code using the Sequel.odbc command, I receive the following error:

**ODBC::Error: IM003 (0) [iODBC][Driver Manager]Specified driver could not be loaded.**

This is as far as I can get. I used to receive another error first, but managed to solve that by redoing the configuration part. Guess I missed something there.

**EDIT**

This is the code for my base talker class. It basically loads a YAML file like rails does, holding the database settings and establishes a connection to the database.
This seems to be working, trying it manually returns me a DB object from sequel:

```
module Talkers
  require 'yaml'
  require 'sequel'

  class BaseTalker
    # This function will load the desired settings as a hash from the database.yml file
    # in the config folder. The data will be returned as a hash following the standard
    # YAML structure.
    def self.load_config(name)
      cfg = YAML::load(File.open(File.join(ENV['API_ROOT'], 'config', 'database.yml')))
      cfg.key?(name) ? cfg[name] : nil
    end

    # This function will establish a connection with the Florensia User database and return
    # the Sequel database object, so that queries can be executed against the database.
    def self.connect_to_user_db
      settings = self.load_config("florensia_user_#{ENV['RACK_ENV']}")
      Sequel.odbc settings['dsn'], :db_type => settings['adapter'], :user => settings['user'], :password => settings['password']
    end
  end
end
```

The class below inherits from the talker and performs certain actions for a User. It contains the DB logic specific to the game. When I call this logic, I receive the errors:

```
module Talkers
  require 'yaml'
  require 'sequel'

  class LoginDbTalker < BaseTalker
    #
    # Bans the specified User from the game. The function requires the following information
    # to be supplied in order for the ban to be properly set:
    # - id : The identifier of the account.
    # - gm_name : The name of the GM setting the ban.
    # - punish_code : The punishment code being applied on the account.
    # - days : The duration of the ban in days, starting from today.
    #
    # The function will return true if the ban has been properly set; otherwise the function
    # will return false.
    def self.ban_user(options = {})
      return false if options.empty?
      db = self.connect_to_user_db
      ds = db[:tbl_User].filter(:id => options[:id])
      ps = ds.prepare(:update, :apply_ban)
      ps.call(
          :punishcode => options[:punish_code],
          :punishstory => "Banned by #{options[:gm_name]}",
          :punishdate => Date.today,
          :punishfreedate => (options[:days].to_i == -1) ? (Date.today + (30 * 265)) : (Date.today + options[:days].to_i))
      true
    rescue Exception => e
      puts "Exception caught in ban_user: #{e.to_s}"
      puts "Provided variables: id=#{options[:id]}, gm_name=#{options[:gm_name]}, punish_code=#{options[:punish_code]}, days=#{options[:days]}"
      false
    end
    #
    # Unbans the specified User from the game. The function requires the following information
    # to be supplied in order for the ban to be properly lifted:
    # - id : The identifier of the account.
    # - gm_name : The name of the GM removing the ban.
    #
    # The function will return true if the ban has been properly lifted; otherwise the function
    # will return false.
    def self.unban_user(options = {})
      db = self.connect_to_user_db
      ds = db[:tbl_User].filter(:id => options[:id])
      ps = ds.prepare(:update, :lift_ban)
      ps.call(
          :punishcode => '0',
          :punishstory => "Ban removed by #{options[:gm_name]}",
          :punishdate => Date.today,
          :punishfreedate => Date.today
      )
      true
    rescue Exception => e
      puts "Exception caught in unban_user: #{e.to_s}"
      puts "Provided variables: id=#{options[:id]}, gm_name=#{options[:gm_name]}"
      false
    end
    #
    # Kicks the specified User from the game, regardless on the server or character he currently is on.
    # This requires a direct connection to the game servers so a specialized command can be sent that
    # instruct the server to close the connection with the offending player.
    # The function returns true if the kick succeeded; otherwise false.
    def self.kick_player(id)
      false
    end
  end
end
```

Calling any of the ban/unban functions results in the error message.

**EDIT2**

I've added the folder /Library/ODBC and linked all config files to there for iODBC. This removes the error I had before and now brings me this error:

**ODBC::Error: 01000 (20002) [FreeTDS][SQL Server]Adaptive Server connection failed**

So it seems I made some progress again

Comment: You should show your code, the simplest possible test case that _should_ work but fails.

Comment: added the source code as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend you use the tinytds adapter instead of the odbc adapter if you are connecting to Microsoft SQL Server from OS X.  I know there are people who have got Sequel/ODBC running on non-Windows boxes, but I only have experience with Sequel/ODBC on Windows.